# mysql workbench how to change a colums spaces for underscores

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've recently just finished setting up a MySQL database but I forgot to add the underscores and I don't want to go through all ten thousand of the entries and add them little by little is a quick way of doing this? also this is only needed in one column of the database

```
'222', '1', 'R', '219', '-', 'MTG 8900 LO Level Alarm', '1', 'int16', 'N'
'223', '1', 'R', '220', '-', 'MTG 8900 LL Level Alarm', '1', 'int16', 'N'
'224', '1', 'R', '221', '-', 'MTG 8900 HI Level Alarm', '1', 'int16', 'N'
'225', '1', 'R', '222', '-', 'MTG 8900 HH Level Alarm', '1', 'int16', 'N'
'226', '1', 'R', '223', '-', 'MTG 8900 Addresses', '1', 'int16', 'N'
'227', '1', 'R', '224', '-', 'MTG 8900 Alarm Status', '1', 'int16', 'N'
'228', '1', 'R', '225', '-', 'MTG 8900 Internal Guage Temp', '1', 'int16', 
'N'
'229', '1', 'R', '226', '-', 'MTG 8900 RDU Display', '1', 'int16', 'N'
'230', '1', 'R', '227', '-', 'MTG 8900 Returned Signal Strength', '1', 
'int16', 'N'
'231', '1', 'R', '228', '-', 'MTG 8900 Inputs', '1', 'int16', 'N'
'232', '1', 'R', '229', '-', 'MTG 8900 Outputs', '1', 'int16', 'N'
'233', '1', 'R', '230', '-', 'MTG 8900 Software Rev', '1', 'int16', 'N'
'234', '1', 'R', '231', '-', 'MTG 8900 Guage Type ', '1', 'int16', 'N'
'235', '1', 'R', '232', '-', 'MTG 8900 Tank ID', '1', 'int16', 'N'
'236', '1', 'R', '233', '-', 'MTG 8900 Max Wkg Level', '1', 'int16', 'N'
'237', '1', 'R', '234', '-', 'MTG 8900 Current Display', '1', 'int16', 'N'
'238', '1', 'R', '235', '-', 'MTG 8900 Temp Type', '1', 'int16', 'N'
'239', '1', 'R', '236', '-', 'MTG 8900 No of Bulbs', '1', 'int16', 'N'
'240', '1', 'R', '237', '-', 'MTG 8900 Sensitivity', '1', 'int16', 'N'
'241', '1', 'R', '238', '-', 'MTG 8900 Raw Data', '1', 'int16', 'N'
```

i need the '_' in the MTG table

Comment: this is just in one column i need this

Comment: Could you please post the table definition (or a reduced version including the relevant column), and some example rows as they are now and as you want them? Without such data it is impossible to understand what you are asking...

Comment: It is possible paste your table structure along with data

Answer (score 0):

If it's only 1 column and all the whitespace replace by "_", you can do this :

```
UDPATE myTable 
SET mycolumn = REPLACE(mycolumn, ' ', '_');
```

Comment: where would i execute this command if you don't mind me asking

Comment: update pro42_device_register 
SET device_register_variable = REPLACE(device_register_variable, '  ', '_'); that is what i've excuted but it hasnt worked

Comment: 08:41:23 update pro42_device_register SET device_register_variable = REPLACE(device_register_variable, ' ', '_') Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect. 0.000 sec

Comment: Follow the directive, disable this option ;)